# Alexandria Lisp Manual & Implementation

Tags: package, common-lisp, code-documentation

The ALEXANDRIA package seems to be widely-used in the common-lisp community. However, the only documentation I've found is a draft version of a manual, which leads to a couple of questions:

1) There are a number of macros, like `reversef`, which are listed under the "Conses" heading, but which also seem to work for "Sequences" in general:

```
(defparameter vec (vector 1 2 3))
#(1 2 3)
(alexandria:reversef vec)
#(3 2 1)
vec
#(3 2 1)
```

Is there some technical reason they are put under "Conses"?

2) Is there a way to look inside the macros to see how they are constructed? Doing a macroexpand on them reaches a wall:

```
(macroexpand '(alexandria:rotate vec))
(ALEXANDRIA.0.DEV:ROTATE VEC)
```

3) Is there a more formal spec for Alexandria available?

Answer (score 3):

`REVERSEF` should be listed under *sequences*.

`ROTATE` is not a *macro*. It's a *function*. Using `macroexpand` will have no effect on a function, since it is not a macro.

Comment: Also had occasion to use `alexandria:map-product` recently, which the draft manual says returns a list, but it can also return a vector. Is any additional Alexandria documentation available?